# New Roof - Exposed Nail Heads

Tags: roof, nails

Have new roof with exposed nail heads at ridge.  Roofer's fix was to cut tiny squares of shingle and goop/glue to top of nail heads.  Need inputs from roofers; what is the proper way to fix the exposed nail heads?  Any code number for this?  Also, have they stopped using drip edge?

Comment: Is it all the way across the ridge? Or just 4 nails at one end?

Comment: They were random.  Not all in one place.

Comment: Confirm: these exposed nail heads are at multiple locations along the ridge? Sounds pretty skeevy to me.

Comment: If they're seen random across the whole ridge, then it's a substandard job and will leak. @wallyk's answer shows how it should be done.  At one end you will have nails where the next shingle can't cover the nails because there is no next shingle and a shingle should be glued to cover.  Not making this an answer caz it says no more than wallyk's correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

There might only be exposed nail heads at the end(s) of the ridge.  The other nail heads should be covered by the adjacent ridge cap shingle, like this (from [here](http://www.hammerzone.com/archives/roof/maintenance/reshingle_3tab/asphalt/peak_details.htm)):

[image]

A professional would hide the last nail heads by gluing an end piece on like this:
[image]

That seems like what you are describing.  If so, there should be **no** nail heads exposed.

If you paid for the roof, have the guys come back and fix it at their expense.

As for drip edge, that might vary according to local climate and neighborhood restrictions.  (I used to live in a neighborhood which required cedar shake roofs with non-metallic edges.  The HOA successfully sued a homeowner who did otherwise.)  Check with your neighbors.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  It appears the kinda-roofer I had via a kinda General Contractor needs to learn a few lessons.  When I mentioned to at least put some Henrys on the nail heads, I just got a blank stare.  Oh Well, but the basics looks OK.  This is minor compared to some other issues not mentioned here.  Thanks again.